# How to (with tailwind) fix a div top-bottom but make it flex left-right

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have 2 divs.

- right div -- I want it to be scrollable with a fixed width (600px)
- left div -- I want it to be fixed (not scrollable) and fill up the entire screen (except for the navbar) that's not taken by the right div (flex auto).

However, it seems like `fixed` does not work with flex. So I'm not sure what's the best way to do this. Any ideas?

My code: https://play.tailwindcss.com/oodPsyoJWo

Note that I can't simply remove the fixed property inside the left div in my code because that would make it scrollable.

Comment: Removing `fixed` in `<div class="fixed top-[65px] left-0 bottom-0 z-40 h-screen flex-auto bg-green-500">` doesn't bring the expected result?

Comment: See: https://play.tailwindcss.com/sG8a9Cu19I

Comment: It doesn't because the left div is not fixed. You can still scroll it. I want it to be not scrollable and only the right div is scrollable.

Comment: Have you tried using ```align-self: start``` on the second dive that you don't want to grow. Flex items will grow to stretch their container by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want a fixed nav at the top of the page followed by two columns, where one column is fixed in width and scrolls, while the other doesn't scroll and fills the rest of the screen remaining after accounting for the fixed column.

This is a great case for CSS grid.  Basically, the outermost container (`body` in the demo below) creates a grid that has two rows: the first (for the navigation) uses max-content for its height and the second row fills the remaining space.  Setting the body to 100vh (`h-screen`), ensures that it fills the screen entirely.

It also has two columns.  The second is 600px while the first takes up the remaining space.  Adding `col-span-full` to the header causes it to take up the whole width of the grid.

Setting the overflow to hidden on the body and then adding `overflow-y-auto` to the main allows just that one column to scroll as needed.

#### Working snippet (open in full screen to test)

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<body class="grid h-screen grid-rows-[max-content_1fr] grid-cols-[1fr_600px]  overflow-hidden">
  <header class="col-span-full">
    <nav class="flex flex-col gap-4 p-4 md:flex-row md:justify-between">
      <h2 class="text-xl font-bold">Fixed nav height is the max height of contents</h2>
      <p>Nav always fixed to the top of the page</p>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <aside class="bg-green-500 p-4">
    <h2 class="mb-2 text-xl font-bold">Fixed fluid-width column<br />overflow is hidden</h2>
  </aside>
  <main class="overflow-y-auto bg-green-700 p-4">
    <h2 class="mb-2 text-xl font-bold">Fixed 600px width column<br />scroll with overflow-y-auto</h2>
    <p class="mb-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, rerum. Qui eum minus mollitia voluptates, voluptate vel tenetur? Molestias expedita porro esse laborum ipsa veritatis illo ab consequatur nesciunt voluptate.</p>
    <p class="mb-2">Distinctio tenetur ratione, doloremque omnis quae quam, asperiores rerum exercitationem libero neque nisi aliquid non voluptatem incidunt cumque iusto ea laboriosam magni animi earum? Rerum odio molestias aut quaerat omnis.</p>
    <p class="mb-2">Explicabo officiis quos asperiores officia iure, doloremque vitae assumenda architecto error enim exercitationem alias itaque suscipit voluptate, amet pariatur nihil ipsum omnis quae voluptatum harum distinctio obcaecati autem! Corporis, expedita?</p>
    <p class="mb-2">Veniam non minus nam pariatur, cumque porro accusamus facilis rem libero ducimus laudantium sequi, ut quisquam deleniti sunt odit asperiores consectetur labore dolore voluptatem neque. Debitis sapiente ea itaque velit!</p>
    <p class="mb-2">Fuga velit deserunt, sapiente et quos inventore ex vero laborum, at aspernatur, quam cum. Repellendus reprehenderit distinctio, maxime quia dolores in aliquid debitis nobis ipsam nisi quidem. Velit, adipisci veritatis!</p>
    <p class="mb-2">Pariatur quisquam ducimus ex quia maiores quo atque quasi perspiciatis repellendus? Voluptate perferendis illum beatae, natus cumque eveniet labore nesciunt fugiat modi inventore sed? Quibusdam possimus est magnam facere alias?</p>
    <p class="mb-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, rerum. Qui eum minus mollitia voluptates, voluptate vel tenetur? Molestias expedita porro esse laborum ipsa veritatis illo ab consequatur nesciunt voluptate.</p>
    <p class="mb-2">Distinctio tenetur ratione, doloremque omnis quae quam, asperiores rerum exercitationem libero neque nisi aliquid non voluptatem incidunt cumque iusto ea laboriosam magni animi earum? Rerum odio molestias aut quaerat omnis.</p>
    <p class="mb-2">Explicabo officiis quos asperiores officia iure, doloremque vitae assumenda architecto error enim exercitationem alias itaque suscipit voluptate, amet pariatur nihil ipsum omnis quae voluptatum harum distinctio obcaecati autem! Corporis, expedita?</p>
    <p class="mb-2">Veniam non minus nam pariatur, cumque porro accusamus facilis rem libero ducimus laudantium sequi, ut quisquam deleniti sunt odit asperiores consectetur labore dolore voluptatem neque. Debitis sapiente ea itaque velit!</p>
    <p class="mb-2">Fuga velit deserunt, sapiente et quos inventore ex vero laborum, at aspernatur, quam cum. Repellendus reprehenderit distinctio, maxime quia dolores in aliquid debitis nobis ipsam nisi quidem. Velit, adipisci veritatis!</p>
    <p class="mb-2">Pariatur quisquam ducimus ex quia maiores quo atque quasi perspiciatis repellendus? Voluptate perferendis illum beatae, natus cumque eveniet labore nesciunt fugiat modi inventore sed? Quibusdam possimus est magnam facere alias?</p>
  </main>
</body>
```